# How to apply blur effect to nsview / nswindow?

Tags: opacity, nsview, nswindow, osx-yosemite

I'm creating an application to the new OS X Yosemite. I want to create an effect that is very common in this new version, opacity. As an example, the effect that I want, is like the one that exists in the "Mail" application. The left view (where we have "Inbox", "Flagged", "Sent", etc.) have a background blur effect.

How can I apply this effect to my application? This effect is applied to NSView or NSWindow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was searching for this exact thing myself and managed to find an answer which I'll post here although this is quite an old question now.

This method blurs a view and all its subviews:

```c
- (void)blurView:(NSView *)view
{
    NSView *blurView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
    blurView.wantsLayer = YES;
    blurView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor].CGColor;
    blurView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    blurView.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = YES;
    blurView.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;

    CIFilter *saturationFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [saturationFilter setDefaults];
    [saturationFilter setValue:@2.0 forKey:@"inputSaturation"];

    CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"]; // Other blur types are available
    [blurFilter setDefaults];
    [blurFilter setValue:@2.0 forKey:@"inputRadius"];

    blurView.layer.backgroundFilters = @[saturationFilter, blurFilter];

    [view addSubview:blurView];

    [blurView.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Or in Swift:

```swift
private func blur(view: NSView!) {
        var blurView = NSView(frame: view.bounds)
        blurView.wantsLayer = true
        blurView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
        blurView.layer?.masksToBounds = true
        blurView.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = true
        blurView.layer?.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true

        var satFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        satFilter.setDefaults()
        satFilter.setValue(NSNumber(float: 2.0), forKey: "inputSaturation")

        var blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        blurFilter.setDefaults()
        blurFilter.setValue(NSNumber(float: 2.0), forKey: "inputRadius")

        blurView.layer?.backgroundFilters = [satFilter, blurFilter]

        view.addSubview(blurView)

        blurView.layer?.needsDisplay()
    }
```

This code is taken and adapted from an excellent tutorial found [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/10/blurring-views-on-mac/).

Comment: I wonder how you actually used that implementation to achieve what the OP asked for. This blurs (as you said) a view and its content. But he actually wanted to blur the background of the window, and not its content.

Comment: So it's been a while since I answered this but I think you can add the bur view as a subview to a master view which will not be blurred. It's just about ordering the layers / subviews properly. (Again been a while since I've done this so could be wrong).

Comment: Great solution but stopped working in macOS Monterey

Comment: @RobSanders , thanks for this, it works great. I was just wondering, is this still the way to go, or, would we use something like NSVisualEffectView these days?  TY

Comment: @Sentry.co - I am trying it right now on 12.3.1, and, I'm blurring cat photos like crazy!  Seems to be working great?